# Import a large SQL dump via sqlpus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus, dump

There is a dump in .sql format, to be imported to the server. From tools only sqlplus. The problem is that sqlplus requires that after each CREATE TABLE was `/` and only after `/` start creating the table. And dump looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE ...;
CREATE TABLE ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
...
DROP TABLE ...;
CREATE TABLE ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
...
...
```

When it comes to INSERT nothing is inserted because the table is not created. Edit the file is not possible because it is a large (~ 700 MB). How to import the dump?

Comment: SQL*Plus should understand `;` by default.

Comment: my problem was that between the command and the semicolon were blank lines. solution: set sqlblanklines on;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the file /tmp/foo.sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    a integer primary key,
    b integer
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2);
```

running sqlplus:

```
$ sqlplus user/pass@db @/tmp/foo

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Oct 25 10:54:39 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
JServer Release 9.2.0.4.0 - Production


Table created.


1 row created.

SQL>
```

It sounds like you've set delimiter to `/` somewhere. Change it back to `;`.

If you need to edit the file, you can do so with `perl -p -E "s/pattern/replacement/" oldfile.sql > newfile.sql` or similar. (Or, honestly, many editors can handle 700MB files on modern machines with many gigabytes of RAM).